# Hold-out Set -- Smallest Acceptable Size given somewhat rare event?

Tags: model-evaluation, small-sample, rare-events, out-of-sample

I am contemplating the appropriate percent train-test split (e.g. 90%-10%, 80%-20%)

Note I am asking about model evaluation, not cross validation/model building. This is for creating a hold out set to evaluate predictive performance. I'm aware this is difficult in small samples.

I wish to measure how well a model is performing for **N = 300** observations. Not terribly small, but the binary outcome being predicted is a bit unbalanced:

- Let *Y* = 1 when the outcome occurs, 0 otherwise
- *Y =1* for 41 observations.

My plan is to do a hold-out set with a deliberately equal representation of outcomes. So the concern is, if I do 90-10 I'm looking at the event only occuring 4 times in the test set (N = 30). Whereas, if we go the opposite extreme and do 50-50, the training modelwould be modeling for a binary event that only occurs 20 times in the training data (N = 150), making it potentially quite difficult to detect distribution.

Essentially what I'm getting at is, is it more valuble to take test set from tiny --> small (but in turn take the train set from medium to small), or to keep training set as large as possible at the cost of a tiny test set? I'm sure the answer is circumstantial and somewhere in the middle. **Will I break things if my test set has an outcome that only occurs 4 times in 30 observations? What's a reasonable minimum?**